# Hashes vs arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Are there associative arrays in Ruby?
Or associative arrays are just hashes for Ruby?

I heard in Ruby hashes and associative arrays aren't the same thing (like in some other languages).

So are there practical difference between associative arrays and hashes?

Comment: There are no "associative arrays" in ruby. That's an idiosyncrasy of PHP.

Comment: Yay, golden badge superpowers :)

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate, but the down votes are really unnecessary. There's nothing wrong with being a newbie and asking a good question, just because others have asked it before.

Comment: @jdl: Technically, there *is* something wrong. Failure to search before asking.

Comment: I agree with both of you, but it's a very straightforward search. I searched on "ruby associative arrays" and the original question was at the top of the list.  Same when I used Google to search "ruby associative arrays site:stackoverflow.com".

Comment: You're right and I found those post, but I read there: _"in Ruby they're a separate thing."_ And this was for me confusing that associative arrays and hashes are separated things in Ruby. So I just asked. Now I notice that that author was thinking about normal arrays not associative.

Comment: @Jensky: yeah. he didn't say "associative arrays". But it could be misunderstood, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby there's a strict difference between Array and Hash:

```
array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
array[2]
# => 3

hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
hash[:a]
# => 1
hash[1]
# => nil
```

Unlike PHP, arrays are always a series of zero or more objects that have a particular ordering and hashes are key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks, now that is clearly.